# Track User Sessions

Tags: iis-7

I have a relatively low-traffic site where i'd like to 'record' and 'play-back' user sessions. Something that shows me - not just pages visited but time spent on a given page and any other collectible events.

utilities and strategies that records users' interactions within my site - somewhere beyond raw log format - or working with Log Parser on an ad hoc basis. Am willing to consider 3rd party $$ utilities but they have to be in the sub-enterprise bin.

IIS7 specific or not

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These services might do what your looking for:

[clicktale](http://www.clicktale.com/default.aspx)

[crazyegg](http://crazyegg.com/)